# Why is the object always empty?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a little problem with my Ajax calls. Maybe i do not have the right approach here or i did not understand it correctly.

Here is what i do:
i create a new object once and set a value with the function set_value for a variable defined in the __constructor in createobj.php

```
$obj->set_value(10);
```

The object is created in class_obj.php. and the value is 10.

Then i make an ajaxcall with jquery and json:

```
$jq.getJSON(ajaxcall.php? + options, function(data) {
```

But when i call the obj in ajaxcall.php again it is empty? I do not understand why, so i appreciate any tipps, tutorials ebooks and your help for better understanding.

How can i achieve it, that i can access the same object created in createobj.php in ajaxcall.php with all values, setting new ones etc.? So a "global" object. Or do i have to send the obj with the ajaxcall?

Thank you for bringing light into the dark ;)

Comment: post the code here or even better to a place such as ideone.com - there's no way to see what might be wrong without the code

Comment: can you give me more code? how can you get <options> in your .php file?

Comment: You _might_ be interested in http://docs.php.net/intro.session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're expecting the value to stay as it was when you execute another script (the AJAX script), which won't work, they will act as completely different scripts, so no information will be passed between them.

You'd either have to set the value to a SESSION, or save it in some way (e.g. to a database) and then "load" the values from an ID set in a SESSION variable.

Comment: hm when i have a header.php which initiates the object and is included in both files the createobj.php  and ajaxcall.php would this work?

Comment: Not unless you are re-loading the information from somewhere inside the class. As I suggested, a database + session variable to store an ID would likely work best.

Comment: Ah i thought an object is always setted and can be accessed in another file, when it is initiated in an header element. So the only way to do this is by session or database? Thank you but then i must rethink my solution completely, because saving a multidimensional array with e.g. 100 keys into session is not best for performance right?